# Solidity version mismatch

Tags: solidity, truffle

My smart contract has `pragma solidity 0.4.18;`

According to [Solidity: Best practices - Which compiler version should I use? Advantages / Disadvantages](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50071/solidity-best-practices-which-compiler-version-should-i-use-advantages-dis), this pragma will work on any compiler from 0.4.18 and upwards.

```
$ truffle version
Truffle v5.1.65 (core: 5.1.65)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.4
Web3.js v1.2.9
$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Wrestling.sol

CompileError: /F/hackernoon/contracts/Wrestling.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.4.18;
^---------------------^

Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity 0.4.18".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
(See https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)
```

My compiler version is 0.5.16, which I think is greater than 0.4.18. But truffle fails to compile my file.

I checked https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/blob/gh-pages/bin/soljson-v0.5.16%2Bcommit.9c3226ce.js, it doesn't look like a nightly build.

What caused the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compile from one version and upwards, you need to include symbol `^`:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
```

However, this will only take up to version 0.4.26, which is the latest from 0.4, but not versions above (0.5, 0.6...). As described in the official documentation:

> `pragma solidity ^0.5.2;`
>
> A source file with the line above does not
> compile with a compiler earlier than version 0.5.2, and it also does
> not work on a compiler starting from version 0.6.0 (this second
> condition is added by using ^). This is because there will be no
> breaking changes until version 0.6.0, so you can always be sure that
> your code compiles the way you intended. The exact version of the
> compiler is not fixed, so that bugfix releases are still possible.

You have two options:

1. Update the pragma from your smart contract to ^0.5.16 (and apply the necessary changes in the contract to the new pragma version)
2. Change the compiler version in truffle to 0.4.18 (in file `truffle-config.js`)

Comment: I still don't understand what `pragma solidity 0.4.18` means without caret.

Comment: It means that you to stick to that specific version of Solidity, so you can only use a compiler version 0.4.18. On the other hand, if you use ^0.4.18, you can use compiler versions 0.4.18, 0.4.19, 0.4.20 ..... 0.4.26. You won't be able though to use 0.5 or higher to avoid breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Pragma is a directive in solidity.js which specifies which compiler version has to be used for current solidity file.

Now whenever you setup truffle by default it sets latest version in your system which is version 0.5+ currently and when you unbox a truffle directory usually the .sol file has version 0.4 dependency which means your project and system dependencies are mismatching.

In order to make your project run, you need to make both version same which can be done in two ways:

By upgrading project version to 0.5 or downgrading system version to 0.4, out of which first approach is preferred as we will use latest version of truffle i.e. 0.5.

You can replace your first line in .sol file as this:

`pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;`

or

`pragma solidity >=0.4.21;`

@Gqqnbig
This should resolve your issue.